# getImage by Label not working in Bundle item

Tags: url, image, model, bundled-product, image-preview

I want to get the image by its label, inside a bundle product's each options selection item. Each selection item is a simple product.

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)
    ->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', $preview_label_standing)
    ->getUrl();
```

The file I am calling the above code is from the path `app\design\frontend\myCustomPackage\myCustomTheme\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle\option\radio.phtml`. Here `$product_id` contains simple product id and `$preview_label_standing` contains the label i have given for my image from the backend.

P.s. And I want to add one more thing the same code is working in my localhost, but not in server :(

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The media gallery gets returned as type `Varien_Data_Collection` and so you need to use the function `getItemsByColumnValue` to filter on it. The following code will allows you to filter your media gallery by label.

```
/** @var Varien_Data_Collection $mediaGallery */
$mediaGallery = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(165)->getMediaGalleryImages();
$filteredMediaGallery = $mediaGallery->getItemsByColumnValue('label', 'test label');
foreach ($filteredMediaGallery as $singleMediaGallery) {
    $mediaUrl = $singleMediaGallery->getUrl());
}
```

**Note: that this will still be a collection and so you will need to loop through the results, or simply get the first item**